# How can I detect if Chrome thinks the current page is a secure origin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, geolocation, cross-domain

As of Chrome 50, Google have removed the ability for Chrome to do a Geolocation lookup unless the page hosted on a secure origin.

See https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features

I am building a widget that will be embedded on websites that I do not control, and my widget has some geolocation features. I want to hide geolocation-related UI in my widget if the user is using Chrome and the origin is not considered secure.

How can I detect non-secure origins?

#### Update

My initial idea was to do something like this:

```
const geolocationPermitted = () => {
  return (!window.chrome) || window.location.protocol == 'https:';
}
```

But this test fails When developing locally, since I serve the site from localhost over plain `http`. This is considered secure by Chrome though, and the function above return false.

Comment: When is an origin secure? If it's `https` or only if the certificate is valid?

Comment: If it's **in** a website, the only secure protocol would generally be `https://`, so you'd check for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that Chrome and Firefox do expose this as a property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/isSecureContext

> The `window.isSecureContext` read-only property indicates whether a context is capable of using features that require secure contexts.

My current test is:

```
browserHasLocation = () => {
    return navigator.geolocation && (!window.chrome || window.isSecureContext);
}
```

Comment: Why not check for `isSecureContext` regardless of webbrowser? That way it works on Firefox as well. `browserHasLocation = () => (navigator.geolocation && window.isSecureContext !== false);`

Comment: There's no need to call `window`.  For example, this works: `console.log(isSecureContext)`.  This is noted by MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @Zamicol it's generally good practice to call `window`, as to keep the number of "magic global properties" to a minimum. By assuming that `window` is the only global property, there's no problem naming a new variable `const isSecureContext` because we can still access the original property via `window.isSecureContext`.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome will have a built in way to check for this, as one can't just check for the origin of the page, because the page could be on `https` but inside an iframe that is hosted from an unsecure context etc.

A strong signal that it was a non-secure content issue is to look for the string *"Only secure origins are allowed"* in the error message.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(success) {
      // Origin IS secure
}, function(failure) {
    if(failure.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
      // Origin is NOT secure
    }
  };
});
```

This will work on older browsers, as they won't throw an error for an unsecure origin

Information gotten from the [Chrome Web Updates page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

---

Another way would be to check the protocol, but as noted above, this is not always reliable, for instance when using iframes etc.

```
if ( window.location.protocol == 'https:' ) {
    // SSL enabled
}
```

According to Google the following are generally considered "secure".

- `https://`
- `wss://`
- `file://`
- `chrome-extension://`
- `http://localhost`
- `http://127.0.0.*`
- `*::1.128`

So if one is developing on localhost, a check for that would be needed as well, and if using websockets, one would have to check for `wss` etc.

Adding to that, the list may not be complete, there could be several other scenarios where the origin is considered secure, that would require additional checks, which is why the first method of using the error callback on `getCurrentLocation` should be used.

If developing on localhost, and the script should be used on http(s) protocol only, one could check for both

```
if (window.location.protocol == 'https:' || ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"].indexOf(location.hostname) !== -1) {...
```

Or simply comment out the check during development

Comment: This would work, except it will pop up the UI asking the user if they want to allow the page to access their location. I have a button in my widget that says 'Use my location', and I don't want to ask for the user's location before they click the button. The user is asked for location before they have understood why the page wants their location.

I want to hide the `Use my location` button entirely if the origin is not secure.

Comment: This is the way Google says you should check for an unsecure origin, so I'd go with that. The other way is to check if the protocol is `https://`, but as I noted in the answer above, that's not reliable in all cases

Answer (score 1):

Use `isSecureContext`, for example, `console.log(isSecureContext)`.

This is noted by MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: This is IMHO the correct answer since HTTP is considered secure when it's launched from localhost.